# Im trying to build a dynamic meta stream object that waits for some of the streams to complete before running

Tags: angular, asynchronous, reactive

> **The problem:**

I have many stream feeding into a service. When a button is clicked all the alive components that are currently subscribed to their service streams, update said streams. I need to iterate through all the streams in that service and build a json object out of the streams that are not null.

Stream Service

```
masterSubmit$: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
addForm$: BehaviorSubject<model> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
addSubForm$: BehaviorSubject<otherModel> = new BehaviorSubject(null);

RxJSOperatorThatEmitsAllStreamsAtSameTime(
masterSubmit$,
addForm$,
addSubForm$,
).subscribe((data) => {
  if(data[0] == null){
    return;
  }
  if(data[1] != null){
    jsonObject.properties = {data[1]}
  }
  etc..

  if(data[0] == 'postNewThingy'){
    this.apiStuff.postThingy(jsonObject);
  }
})
```

That is what im going for, any advise would be fantastic! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi You can make a use of combineLatest RXJS operator to wait for all the calls to finish

```
    combineLatest(masterSubmit$,
addForm$,
addSubForm$,).subscribe(
      ([masterSubmit, addForm, addSubForm]) => {

        console.log(
          `masterSubmit: ${masterSubmit},
         addForm: ${addForm},
         addSubForm: ${addSubForm}`
        );
      }
    );
```

Comment: will this work if not all of them do finish? the problem is that different components will be alive each time the user clicks submit and only those components will call their streams, so in this case only master submit and addForm would complete

Comment: With your requirement i think combineLatest will work for you.

Comment: ok I actually tried this one, the problem i found is that it calls procedurally. so in my case every time one of the streams updates it would look like this 
One: 1$ = stuff, 2$ = null, 3$ = null 
Two: 1$ = stuff, 2$ = stuff, 3$ = null
Thr: 1$ = stuff, 2$ = stuff, 3$ = stuff

my problem is that after one two and three the api is called. So three objects would be added to the database.